# Rado graph and linear algebra

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, infinite-combinatorics

Let $V = \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ be the set of integers and let $\mathcal{G} = (V, E)$ be an (undirected) Rado graph on $V$. Let $W = \bigoplus_{i = 0}^{\infty} \mathbb{F}_2$ and write $x_i$ for the $i$-th standard basis vector of $W$. Let $b$ be the unique bilinear map $W \times W \rightarrow W$ such that
$$
b(x_i, x_j) = e(i, j) (x_i + x_j),
$$
where $e(i, j) = 1$ if there is an edge between $i$ and $j$ in $\mathcal{G}$, and $0$ otherwise.

Suppose that we have another basis $(y_i)$ of $W$ such that
$$
b(y_i, y_j) \in \langle y_i, y_j \rangle.
$$
Is it true that $y_i = x_{\sigma(i)}$ for some permutation $\sigma$ of $V$?

This question naturally came up in some computations in Galois cohomology.

Comment: What does $\in$ mean here? And what does $\langle\bullet,\bullet\rangle$ mean?

Comment: (Just to be sure.)

Comment: This means that the vector $b(y_i, y_j)$ is an element in the span of the vectors $y_i$ and $y_j$, i.e. $\{0, y_i, y_j, y_i + y_j\}$